# How to customize the lightning-map location list?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-map

Is it possible to modify how the locations on the right are displayed? And if so - how? I can control the title but below it, it will always display either latitude and longitude or the address. It would be nice to show other information there as well.

[image: lightning map with location list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lightning-map doesn't support this feature, but you could always hide the location details list view using `list-view="hidden"`
and use a custom component to show any details you want to show.

`[lightning-map][1]` takes an array of map-markers, you can add `value` to know which marker is selected.
You have `onmarkerselect={handleMarkerSelect} selected-marker-value={selectedMarkerValue}`

Comment: As good and I guess unsurprising as it gets. I wonder how other people solve this as I couldn't even find a similar question for this issue. Thanks for the feedback!